# JavaScript Slint - report XML for Hudson

Tags: javascript, hudson, jenkins, jslint, jslint4java

I am using [JavaScript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/index.htm) for checking JavaScript source code. It's working fine with recursive analysis showing results in command window, but I would like to integrate JavaScript Lint results to Hudson (running JavaScript Lint from batch file).
How can I get log of JavaScript Lint saved to XML?
There are output format configuration in JavaScript Lint, but those customize format of error message.

Thank you in advance,
Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for applying Jslint in Hudson. Instead of JavaScript Lint there is [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/) which reports in XML format.
Here is step by step instructions:

1. Download jslint4java
2. Prepare Ant script which prepares list of all JS files in project recursively, example:

   ```
   <project name="JSlint" default="jslint" basedir=".">
   <description>
       Verify JS files
   </description>
   <target name="jslint" description="Run the JSLint tool on JS files">
   <fileset dir="ProjectForVerification/js" id="jsfiles.raw">
   <include name="*.js" />
   <exclude name="*.min.js" />
   </fileset>
   <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="jsfiles.clean" refid="jsfiles.raw" />
   <exec executable="java" output="jslint.xml">
   <arg line="-jar jslint4java.jar --report xml ${jsfiles.clean}" />
   </exec>
   </target>
   </project>
   ```
3. Apply Ant script in Hudson for a job and select Jslint output file name (jslint.xml) in 'Report Violations'

Credits: [Here is useful post](https://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/jenkins-ci-jslint-javascript-quality-checking) which I found on this topic.

Comment: Rather than invoking jslint4java as an executable you may find the [ant task](http://docs.jslint4java.googlecode.com/git/2.0.1/ant.html) more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's interested, here's a Maven POM snippet we use to run JSlint:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>jslint</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <taskdef name="jslint" classname="com.googlecode.jslint4java.ant.JSLintTask" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
            <jslint encoding="UTF-8" options="indent=4,evil,laxbreak">
              <formatter type="plain" />
              <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/javascript" includes="**/*.js" />
            </jslint>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jslint4java</groupId>
        <artifactId>jslint4java-ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: You should really upgrade to a newer jslint4java. v2.0.0 comes with a maven plugin, which should work better for your use case.